Finding general form for matrix $M$ given conditions on $M^2$ and $(\text{adj}(M))^2$?
Let $M$ be a matrix with real coefficients.
If $M^2 = I \land (\text{adj}(M))^2 = I$, find a general form for $M$ (in terms of any parameters of your choice, provided you give the range of values the parameters can take).
P.S: I thought using some decomposition of $M$ in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors could help, then realized I have no idea how to relate eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $\text{adj}(M)$ with the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $M$, so not sure.

If $M^2=I$, then the condition $(\text{adj}(M))^2 = I$ is always satisfied.
If $M^2=I$, you have $M^{-1}=M$ and $\det(M)=\pm 1$. Then,
$$\text{adj}(M) = \det(M)M^{-1} = \det(M)M$$
$$(\text{adj}(M))^2 = \det(M)^2 M^2 = 1\cdot I = I$$
Thus, you just need the condition $M^2=I$, which means that $M$ is an involutory matrix.
There are several families of matrices with this property such as diagonal matrices with entries $\pm 1$, Householder matrices...
If you set the size of the matrix, you can also come up with specific equations by considering a matrix with generic entries.

Is there any necessary and sufficient condition on involutory matrices...

Consider a $n\times n$ matrix with arbitrary entries for any $n$ you want. Compute the square of the matrix and equate the result to the identity matrix of order $n$. The solutions of the system of $n^2$ equations give you the entries of all involutory matrices that exist and you can deduce relationships between the parameters. You can also take a look at other properties of involutory matrices in case you are looking for general solutions in specific families of matrices. For example, an orthogonal symmetric matrix is involutory. Or if $\frac{1}{2}(M+I)$ is idempotent, then $M$ is involutory.
